# Trying to use GIT on project deleted my files

Tags: git

I've inherited a project from aonther programmer and it once have source-controlled by GIT.
No I've been working on the project for more than a year and jist wanted to connect it to GIT again to have some kind of revision control and somehow it started by reverting all my source code to this year-old version.

Is there ANY way I can recover my latest files to before I enabled GIT?

---

[edit] as requested :

`git stash list` outputs :

```
stash@{0}: WIP on master: 4dc75b5 f<C3><B8>r refactor
stash@{1}: WIP on master: 4dc75b5 f<C3><B8>r refactor
```

`git reflog` outputs :

```
4dc75b5 (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD
4dc75b5 (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to HEAD
4dc75b5 (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{2}: commit: f<C3><B8>r refactor
b0a5b55 HEAD@{3}: commit: First publish
6119f77 (origin/master) HEAD@{4}: commit (initial): Add .gitignore and .gitattributes.
```

Comment: You would need to explain what you did, what command you executed. Did you `git clone`? Also, where did you execute them? On which directory?

Comment: Well..  Thats the thing.
Im using visual studio an just set GIT as the source control, so I'm not actually sure what it did.
I was hoping there were som command-line commands where I could see what had been done.

Comment: Now it is too late for that. Never use features (ANY!) if you are not sure what they do and what may be implications fo execuitng it.

Comment: Could it be that you've switched to an old branch? You can use `git branch -a` to list all available branches as well as check which branch you're at right now.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the actions you ran through Visual Studio ?

Comment: Well @LeGEC . I simply went to tools, source control, plug-in Selection and chose "Git" as my current plugin.

It must've been used before as the plugin reverted to the latest version whered it was used ( more than a year ago)
Or thats my thory anyway.

Comment: As the OP stated : he does not seem to have much experience with git, so he probably also needs assistance in formulating his question.

Comment: @HenrikClausen : from the command line, `cd` into your project's directory, and run : 1. `git stash list`, 2. `git reflog` ; please mention in your question if you see any output from those commands.

Comment: Ok ; from your description, I guess the `f<C3><B8>r refactor` commit was not created by you. correct ?

Comment: Still from the command line : 1. confirm that `git status` tells you that there are no modified files and no changes to commit, 2. if 1. is true, run `git stash apply`

Comment: Well there are no modified files as its an ancient version I see now. Should I still run the apply?

Comment: Yes (you have nothing to lose : the current state is correctly stored in commit `4dc75b5`)

Comment: Well it seems I have one modified file..  Propably something I was doing just before discovering the problem..  Can I revert that one file first?

Comment: it looks like the first stash does not contain what you want. 1. cancel the modifications on said file : `git checkout -- that/file` (again : that file's content is stored somewhere so it is safe to revert) 2. try applying the second stash : `git stash apply stash@{1}`

Comment: HOLY MOLY!
My stuff IS BACK!!!

I wish I could somehow thank you better than just points in SO.

Backup, backup, backup.

THANK YOU.  You really saved my day.  Good thing I'm working home due to the virus, or else my colleagues would think I was suffering a stroke before.

Comment: Gad I could help -- many other people could have guided you to that. Just don't collapse on us ;)

Comment: And do commit your changes, to avoid another stroke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect your stash, and the reflog : those are two places where git may store files without referencing them from a commit.

- from a command line :

```sh
# go to the directory of your project
$ cd path/to/project

# to view if anything is stashed away :
$ git stash list

# to view the reflog :
$ git reflog
```

- from a GUI tool : search in the menus an entry which would indicate "view list of stashes" / "view reflog"

---

It looks like you have some changes stashed away (`git stash list` mentions two lines).

You can view the content of those stashes :

```sh
# to view the content of the latest stash :
$ git stash show       # view the list of files stored in the first stash
$ git stash show -p    # view the complete diff (-p for 'patch') of the first stash

# to view the content of stash@{1} (the second stash) :
$ git stash show stash@{1}
$ git stash show -p stash@{1}

# obviously : if you have more stashes, you can inspect them using 'stash@{n}',
# 'stash@{0}' if also a valid way to target the latest stash
```

You can also restore a stash on disk :

```sh
git stash apply            # apply stash@{0}
git stash apply stash@{n}  # apply stash@{n}
```

As always : `git help` is your friend, run `git help stash` for more details on how to navigate and restore stashes.

---

Once you have restored your files : *do* store them in a commit

- your GUI tool should correctly guide you to do that
- otherwise, from the command line :

```sh
git add the/files you/want to/commit
# some shortcuts :
git add -u    # add all files that are already tracked by git
git add -A    # add all files you have on disk

git commit

# if you have a remote repo : push that commit to the remote
git push     # push your current branch to its remote counterpart (if it has any)
git push origin HEAD:hclausen/backup   # create a remote branch on the fly
```